# Condition with multiset table

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to condition within this query for the B table as labeled below:

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE tablename AS(
SEL 
    B.id,
    c1 AS segment,
    c2,
    c3,
    c4
FROM (SEL id FROM table0 GROUP BY 1) B
JOIN table3 C
ON B.id = C.cct_id
AND C.m_id = 0909
```

Can I just add the conditions within the () as below:

```
FROM (SEL id FROM table0 WHERE status = 1 AND mobile = 1 GROUP BY 1) B
```

I just want to select those ids from table0 that have status and mobile = 1. Those columns are both part of table0. This is teradata.

Comment: So you just want to add a where clause to your derived table?  Yes, you can certainly do that.

Comment: you mean  you didn't test it and decided to write this post instead?

Comment: I did test it, and it spooled so I wanted to confirm that it wasn't those conditions causing the issue

Comment: then ask the right question , show us what you tried and what you got (either wrong result or error message) and then show us what's your expected result

Comment: To add to the comment from  @eshirvana,  are you spooling out on the select, or on the table creation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this query?

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE tablename AS(
SEL 
    B.id,
    c1 AS segment,
    c2,
    c3,
    c4
FROM (SEL id FROM table0 WHERE status = 1 AND mobile = 1 GROUP BY 1) B
JOIN table3 C
ON B.id = C.cct_id
AND C.m_id = 0909)
```

Please explain What difficulties you are facing.